# Converting a char to uppercase in Java

Tags: java, char, uppercase

How could I get the `f` and `l` variables converted to uppercase?

```
String lower = Name.toLowerCase();
int a = Name.indexOf(" ",0);
String first = lower.substring(0, a);
String last = lower.substring(a+1);

char f = first.charAt(0);
char l = last.charAt(0);

System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: which part of the answers to your previous question you didn't understand? My answer there contains an answer to this question.

Comment: @shep - Can you accept BalusC's answer? It will help future searchers.

Answer (score 159):

You can use [`Character#toUpperCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) for this.

```
char fUpper = Character.toUpperCase(f);
char lUpper = Character.toUpperCase(l);
```

It has however some limitations since the world is aware of many more characters than can ever fit in 16bit `char` range. See also the following excerpt of the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29):

> Note: This method cannot handle  [supplementary characters](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#supplementary). To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the [`toUpperCase(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28int%29) method.

Answer (score 47):

Instead of using existing utilities, you may try below conversion using boolean operation:

**To upper case:**

```
 char upperChar = 'l' & 0x5f
```

**To lower case:**

```
   char lowerChar = 'L' ^ 0x20
```

---

**How it works:**

Binary, hex and decimal table:

```
------------------------------------------
| Binary   |   Hexadecimal     | Decimal |
-----------------------------------------
| 1011111  |    0x5f           |  95     |
------------------------------------------
| 100000   |    0x20           |  32     |
------------------------------------------
```

**Let's take an example of small `l` to `L` conversion:**

The binary AND operation: `(l & 0x5f)`

`l` character has **ASCII** 108 and `01101100` is binary represenation.

```
   1101100
&  1011111
-----------
   1001100 = 76 in decimal which is **ASCII** code of L
```

**Similarly the `L` to `l` conversion:**

The binary XOR operation: `(L ^ 0x20)`

```
   1001100
^  0100000
-----------
   1101100 = 108 in decimal which is **ASCII** code of l
```

Comment: I'm honestly shocked that this has 7 votes. While I applaud the clever approach, being clever rarely leads to maintainable code, especially when used in place of a built-in method like `Character.toUpperCase()`. Any users of this should understand it will not handle anything non-ASCII.

Comment: @AdamHewitt this approach work with non-ASCII chars as well e.g. '250', however, few non-ASCII characters wouldn't give expected results.Your point is correct that users should understand right usage of this approach and it should be used mainly for English alphabets.

Comment: I think it should be `c | 0x20` instead of `c ^ 0x20` for lower case. Otherwise, if the character is already lower case, your code will convert it to uppercase

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at the `java.lang.Character` class, it provides a lot of useful methods to convert or test chars.

Comment: +1 I like the answers that providers the user with a reference to go seek the answer

Comment: -1, if we dragnet for students we remove one of SO main benefits. Not spending inordinate amounts of time following peoples nested references across broken links.

Answer (score 15):

```
f = Character.toUpperCase(f);
l = Character.toUpperCase(l);
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you know the chars are lower case, you can subtract the according ASCII value to make them uppercase:

```
char a = 'a';
a -= 32;
System.out.println("a is " + a); //a is A
```

Here is an [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) for reference

Comment: This only works if the string is composed exclusively of ASCII characters. Languages like French, Greek, Spanish, Turkish, etc, have non-ASCII characters with upper/lower forms. This approach wouldn't work in those cases...

Comment: Actually this basic approach *does* work for the most common non-ASCII characters in French, Spanish, German... e.g. `é` `à` `ö` `û` `ñ` ...  So if the OP knows that he will only have to deal with such characters, he can stick to this method for the sake of simplicity and performance.

Comment: Doing calculations with characters to change the case is one of the worst habits, and so not 21st century! There is more than ascii chars!

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(first.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()); 
System.out.println(last.substring(0,1).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: first.substring(0,1) will retrieve substring which is at 0 index of string  and then applying toUpperCase method to that string which will   give you the first character in that string as uppercase

Answer (score 2):

If you are including the apache commons lang jar in your project than the easiest solution would be to do:

```
WordUtils.capitalize(Name)
```

takes care of all the dirty work for you.
See the javadoc [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String))

Alternatively, you also have a capitalizeFully(String) method which also lower cases the rest of the characters.

Comment: The [link](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29) you provided gives 404 error!!!! can you correct it??

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the .toUpperCase() directly on String variables or as an attribute to text fields. Ex: -

```
String str;
TextView txt;

str.toUpperCase();// will change it to all upper case OR
txt.append(str.toUpperCase());
txt.setText(str.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a variable you want split

```
String name = "Your name variable";
char nameChar = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to capitalize first and last character of each word in a sentence with space as delimiter.

**Can be done through `StringBuffer`:**

```
public static String toFirstLastCharUpperAll(String string){
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(string);
        for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
            if(i==0 || sb.charAt(i-1)==' ' //for first character of string/each word
                || i==sb.length()-1 || sb.charAt(i+1)==' ') //for last character of string/each word
                sb.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(i)));
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution for your case - change the first line, let it do just the opposite thing:

```
String lower = Name.toUpperCase ();
```

Of course, it's worth to change its name too.