# Word search inside a file c

Tags: c, matrix

Basically I have almost solved the problem to find an array of words inside a file like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
setrsdfdsrrtdpyrinoeq
weraderelefantewwerrr
trtevhjujhaspescadito
rtxvfdghhgperrodrdvbh
ifghhfgaaasdserpiente
naendsdsadsasafrrsdft
nssdofgfgghghghdddddd
ttegatovvvfgfyhgggggg
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

and output the coordinates where it was found in other file.

However I do not know how to search for vertical words, the code I do is search a word by line and if I find it retun its coordinate.

I know I have to implement othe function to search vertical words but what would be the best approach?

How to change what_coor function to search vertical words?
so it can find for instance the word "ant"

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa*a*aaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb*n*bbb
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr*t*rtr
```

Here is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_OF_LINE 180 //max length of a line 

//search a word in a line if is there returns coordinate
int what_coor ( const char *line, const char *word ){
    const char *p, *x,*y;
    for ( p = line; *p != '\0'; p++ ) {
        x = p;
        y = word;
        for ( ; *x != '\0' && *y != '\0' && *x == *y; x++, y++ )
            ;
            if(*y == '\0')
                  return p - line + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

//reservamos espacio para nuestro myArray 'bidimensional'
char **askMemory(int filas, int cols){
   char **myArray;
   int i;
   /* espacio para el myArray de apuntadores a entero*/
   myArray = (char**)malloc(filas * sizeof(char*));
   if(myArray == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error 1-d \n");
      exit(-1);
   }                                                                               
   /* espacio para los myArrays de letras */
   for(i = 0; i < filas; i++){
      myArray[i] = (char*)malloc(cols * sizeof(char));
      if(myArray[i] == NULL){
         fprintf(stderr, "Error 2-d\n");
         exit(-1);
      }
   }                                                                               
   return myArray;
}
//returns bidimensional array, filling it with a file
char **read (int *ptrNumWords, char *fileName) {
  char line[MAX_OF_LINE];   
  char **myArray;
  int i;
  FILE *f;
  if ( ! ( f = fopen (fileName, "r") ) ) {
    printf ("error opening %s\n", fileName);
    exit (-1);
  }
   while ( fgets (line, MAX_OF_LINE, f) ) {
         *ptrNumWords = *ptrNumWords+1;
  }
  myArray = askMemory (*ptrNumWords, MAX_OF_LINE);
  rewind (f);
  for ( i=0 ; i <*ptrNumWords ; i++ ) {
    fgets (myArray[i], MAX_OF_LINE, f);
    myArray[i][strlen(myArray[i])] = '\0';
  }
  fclose (f);
  return (myArray);
}

//seacrh word and writes output
void searchForIt(int rows, char **array2d , char *target){
     FILE *sal;
     sal = fopen("out.txt","a+");     
     int i, col;
     for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
         col =  what_coor ( array2d[i], target );
         if( col != -1 ){
             fprintf(sal,"\"%s\" \t found on (%d,%d)\n",target, i+1, col);             
             printf ( "\"%s\" \t found on (%d,%d)\n", target, i+1, col );            
         }    
     }
      fclose(sal); 
}


int main (){
  int ptrNumWords = 0;
  int i=0;
  char **array2d;
  array2d  = read(&ptrNumWords, "in.txt"); 
  char *wordsBusca[] = {"gato", "perro", "raton", "elefante", "rino", "serpiente", "pescadito"};
  int len = sizeof(wordsBusca) / sizeof(char *) ;
  for(i =0; i< len; i++){
    searchForIt(ptrNumWords,array2d, wordsBusca[i] );
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can read them into a two dimensional char array and scan horizontally and then vertically using the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

**Summary:**

Step 1: Read the data from the file in a 2D matrix. Each element of matrix will be a `char`.
Step 2: Take the transpose of the matrix.
Step 3: Search for the words horizontally using your function `my_coor`.

**Details:**
You can do Step 1, by getting number of characters per line & number of lines, and then allocating a 2D `char` matrix space dynamically. Then read char by char and keep saving each in correct position in the matrix.
Step 2 requires basic Mathemetics & swapping.
Step 3 you have already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a variant of @0xF1's suggestion a while back in response to another question: see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541444/1967396). In this, I actually turned the 10x10 matrix into a 10x40 matrix, with successive rows in the matrix corresponding to a row in the original 10x10 read from left to right, right to left, top to bottom, and bottom to top.

The advantage of this approach (or the simpler 10x20 - only left to right and top to bottom) is that you now have all the possible directions available for a fast search - you match each word against 40 (or 20) lines without doing any transposing etc. in the meantime.

I think it's a useful improvement.