# How to convert input char to uppercase automatically in Java

Tags: java, char, uppercase

I am using a Scanner class to get the input and want to convert the input to uppercase letter when display it. This is my code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

Since I have convert it to uppercase, but the output is like

```
input: a
c = A;
output: Enter a letter: a
```

PS: The letter "a" is what I typed in the terminal

However I want to it display as an uppercase one. How can I change it?

Comment: You didn't print it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696441/converting-a-char-to-uppercase

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the OP wants to uppercase the tty's own echo of the typed characters.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What does _tty_ stand for?  He hasn't (shown us that he has) printed `c` either :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis comes from TeleTYpewriter - used to refer to a virtual terminal. The point is that when I type into my tty the tty echoes back what I type (unless echo is off) - this is what I think the OP wants to change.

Comment: @Boris Aha, and you are right. Where did you deduce that from OP's question?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because the OP wasn't physically printing the letter but it was in the output - in the same place that it would be if it were typed into the terminal. The OP doesn't user `println` so it would be on the same line as the `Enter a letter: ` text.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, you want to print the letters uppercased _as they're typed_, as BoristheSpider has indicated?

Comment: @rgettman Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`toUpperCase` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) doesn't change the value of the `char` (it can't); it returns the uppercased `char`.  Change

```
Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

to

```
c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
```

**UPDATE**

The updated question now indicates that the uppercased characters are to be printed *as they're typed*.  Java cannot do that, because Java doesn't control how the O/S echoes user input to the screen.  My solution above would only produce additional output, even if it is uppercased.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem. The OP wants the echo on the tty to automatically uppercase characters _as they are typed_.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. But I am still wondering about the display of the input after changing my code.

Comment: @matchaGerry sadly that is impossible from Java.

Comment: @matchaGerry The TTY part was not evident from your question.  Please update the question.

Comment: @rgettman Ok I have updated it. Anyway, thank your answer it is a problem in my code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider since you have told me that it is impossible from Java I think I need to change it when I type.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(c));

Answer (score 0):

Since, java is pass by value, you need to use the return value. Either print `Character.toUpperCase(c)` directly or set it to some `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is An Example Of How You Can Change A Character To UpperCase.

char ch;

```
    System.out.println("Input Characters:");

    ch = (char) System.in.read();
    System.out.println("Character Is: " + ch);

    sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Upper Case: " + Character.toUpperCase(ch));
```