# How can I change an all caps string to capitalize on first letter and then first letter following each space? (Java)

Tags: java, string

Let's say we have a string in java:

```
String str = "ALL CAPS MATE";
```

How can I change it so that it looks like this but for any word:

```
String result = "All Caps Mate";
```

Is there a String method similar to .toUpperCase() or .toLowerCase()?  If there is, I can't seem to find it.

I would appreciate a string method solution.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696441/converting-a-char-to-uppercase.  Loop through the string and upper/lower each character

Comment: There is not such a method in String.

Comment: There is not a builtin, so consider making your own method. make it all lower case, split the string on the spaces into an array, split each element into an array of chars, access the first element of each element in the overall array and make it uppercase, then join everything back together

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.  The OP requires something quite different from the OP of that other question; and the answers to that other question don't apply here.  @Andreas

Comment: As David Wallace stated, this is NOT a duplicate.  It is similar, I'll admit that.  The other questions don't have strings with all caps.  They have mix of lower and upper case and I wanted a solution that applied to strings with all upper case since I'm going to be gathering a lot of data that comes in all caps which is a format I don't want.  Hence I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WordUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang3.text` has a static `capitalizeFully` method, which does what you require.  You'll need the commons lang3 jar in your classpath.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;

WordUtils.capitalizeFully(input);
```

Answer (score 3):

The apache libraries contain some methods to handle this as mentioned by B'bek Shakya and a comment, but if you are looking for a straight native Java solution you would do this as Bald Banta mentioned in the comments.

Here is a code example using streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "fOo bar";
    String transformed = Arrays.stream(input.toLowerCase()
                                            .split(" "))
                               .map(String::toCharArray)
                               .map(arr -> {
                                   arr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[0]);
                                   return arr;
                               })
                               .map(String::valueOf)
                               .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(transformed);
}
```

And the same thing using a more common loop idiom:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "fOo bar";
    String[] words = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        char[] word = words[i].toCharArray();
        word[0] = Character.toUpperCase(word[0]);
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(String.valueOf(word));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would solve your problem by using apache library [for more information](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String))

> org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils

```
 String result= WordUtils.capitalizeFully(str);
```

for more complex one look at this [link](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/5780-string-title-case.html)

and i think your question is already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string?page=1&tab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I don't think this is right.  Did  you test it?

Comment: yeah, my mistake. I did edit it @David Wallace

Comment: I still don't think it's right.  The `capitalize` method only changes the first character of each word.  The OP wants the _opposite_ of that.

Comment: sorry again my mistake, I edited it again though. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Still not right, and I've now applied my downvote.  I strongly suggest you _test_ whatever it is that you intend to post next.

Comment: @DavidWallace thank you sir for enlightenment. After reading the apache doc and trying code by self. I have reach to the solution demand by OP

Comment: OK, I've removed my downvote.  This answer is now correct.