# Is this an alternative to tolower?

Tags: c++, hex

I was solving a very easy problem to convert a character in a string to lowercase, I obviously used `tolower()`. However, I saw someone use this and it was an accepted solution.

**Is this an alternative to `tolower()` function in cpp? If so, why?**

Reference to the problem: https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc126/tasks/abc126_a

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // We want to convert "ABC" to "aBC"
    string S = "ABC";
    S[0] += 0x20;
    // Returns "aBC"
    cout << S << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See answer by Rahul Sharma about how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707004/11087678

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simple ASCII manipulation. You see, the ASCII value to Uppercase A is 65 and lower case a is 97. If you add 32 (0x20 in hex) to 65, you get 97, the lower case a.

As all the alphabets in uppercase and all the alphabets in lowercase are laid out consecutively, you just need to add 32 or 0x20 to any uppercase alphabet and you'll get the lower case one.

Comment: @Theo Of course this is not exactly the same as `tolower()` because this will not work if the character is already lower case (or, indeed any non-upper case character), it will likely produce an unprintable character in that case but definitely not what you want.